# Angular Input Is Not Saved

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a table where the user can enter some stuff to an input field and save them. In the network, the stuff he entered are saved but whenever I refresh the page, the field is empty as if nothing has been entered there. Here is my code, what is wrong with it, and how can I fix it?

[image]

HTML:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="FilePath">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Dosya Yolu </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"> 
                                    <a href (click)="$event.preventDefault()" *ngIf="EditIndex != i">{{row.FilePath}}</a>
                                    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p">
                                        <input matInput name="FilePath" [(ngModel)]="row.FilePath" type="text">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                                            <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="EditIndex != i" (click)="editRow(row, i)">
                                            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                        <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="EditIndex == i"
                                            (click)="editRow(row, undefined)">
                                            <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
```

TS:

```
    testList: ILabConditionResult[] = [];
    HPLCFiles: ILabAnalysisFile[] = [];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ILabAnalysisFile>;
constructor(){
let data: ILabAnalysisFile[] = [];
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
}
        setResponse(response: ILabConditionResult[]) {
        if (response) {
            response = response.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.SequenceNumber - b.SequenceNumber;
            });
        }
        this.testList = response;
        if (this.testList && this.testList.length > 0) {
            this.HPLCFiles = this.testList[0].HPLCFiles;
            this.dataSource.data = this.testList[0].HPLCFiles;
        }
    }
    save(){
    this.labConditionResult.HPLCFiles = this.dataSource.data;
                    this.testList[0].HPLCFiles = this.dataSource.data;
                    this._labService
                        .saveAndGetLabTestResultList(this.testList)
                        .subscribe((response: ILabConditionResult[]) => {
                            response = response.sort((a, b) => {
                                return a.SequenceNumber - b.SequenceNumber;
                            });
                            this.setResponse(response);
                            this.setIndex();
                            response.forEach((x) => {
                                this.setLabConditionResult(x);
                            });
    }
    addNewWorkItem() {
    let tempData = this.dataSource.data.splice(0);
    tempData.unshift({});
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tempData);
    this.EditIndex = 0;
}
    editRow(row: ILabAnalysisFile, index: number) {
    if (index == undefined) {
        if (
            !row.FilePath
        ) {
            return;
        }
        this.fileList = [];
    } else {
        this.fileList = [];
    }
    this.EditIndex = index;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser can hold data until DOM refreshes, I would recommend save it in `localstorage` of the browser

```
// This will store data where Key is identifier and Value can be a dynamic variable
localStorage.setItem(Key, value); // Key & Value should be string before storing

// Retrieve the Value of Key
localStorage.getItem(Key) // String
```

So according to your code:

```
// Store Test list from whatever to string
localStorage.setItem("TestList", JSON.stringify(this.testList));

// Retrieve testlist value and change from string to original form
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("TestList"));
```

Comment: Okay thank you I did that but now, for some reason as soon as  I click save the stuff I wrote is gone. It looks like I just saved an empty input. I've added what it looks like above.

Comment: You need to store the data in your localstorage using localStorage.setItem when the form submits. Also you need to check the value with localStorage.getItem, if you see get it empty then nothing will appear but when you get the data then populate it in the form using ngModel.